Why are the IGBTs of a full bridge inverter of an ultrasonic generator getting hot even at low current (1 A)?
I designed an inverter to use an ultrasonic generator for an ultrasonic homogenizer.
The problem is that even at low current, the switches get abnormally hot(specially two of them Q3 and Q4):

switching frequency is 20kHz
dead time of pwm signals are 1.5µs
IGBTs are FGL60N100
I have good heat sink and fan
My PCB is very symmetric
All gate driver sections are similar
Gate resistor is 50 Ω from gate driver IC HCPL-3120 to gate of IGBT and 1 Ω backward
I put a gate-emitter resistance of 4.7 kΩ
Gate signals are clean and optimized
To provide ZVS condition my ferrite transformer has a very thin gap that makes a leakage inductance of 30 µH
I use PLL method to lock and work on correct working frequency

This is my schematic. I just used FGL60n100 IGBTs instead of 2SK2611 MOSFETs.

This is my PCB:

This is what I got from oscilloscope:
Vge,vec:


Pwm signals of all igbts, from top to bottom Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4

my setup:

I found a similar voltage behavior in a paper. so maybe this is not the cause of overheating!!


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

With both drivers of a half-bridge being driven by the same signal, there's surely some shoot-through happening. That can only be solved by introducing a few microseconds of dead-time between switching one of the transistors off, and switching the other on.
Also, I'm betting that the upper transistors are getting hotter than the lower ones. Q1 and Q3, in this high-side configuration, are are operating as emitter-followers. Their emitters are always \$V_{GE}\$ lower than their gates.
Consequently, with the gate held at +310V, the emitter will be much lower, perhaps +305V, rather than the +310V you would like (ideally).
With \$I_E=1A\$, \$V_{CE}=5V\$, the device would dissipate significant power:
$$ P = I_C\times V_{CE} = 1A \times 5V = 5W $$

nope. Q3 and Q4 are getting hot.
and each IGBT has its own pwm signal. but for safty we interlocked gate driver optocouplers

Each gate drive has its own isolated supply.

@greybeard Yeah, isolated at the output side, but IC1 and IC2 share the same input signal. IC3 and IC4 share an input too.

I mention the DC-DC converters because the gate voltage will not be limited to 310 V, but Ve+12 V (oops - assuming the converters connected reasonably, not really visible from "PCB layout")). Driver pairs IC1&2 shares both signals "Q1"&2, see interlocked gate driver optocouplers comment above, as do IC3&4.
